# multi-threaded signal handling

Tags: multithreading, unix, signals

1. In unix, If a multi-threaded process was sent a signal, which thread will be the one to execute the handling function?
2. if it is a multi-cpu machine, more than 1 thread is running at the same time. which thread will be the on to run the signal handling function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [man 7 signal](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal), all threads in the process share the same signal handler, and if a signal is delivered to a process with multiple threads that have not blocked the signal, one of them is arbitrarily chosen to receive it.

Having a multi-CPU machine will not change these semantics.