# how are signals implemented?

Tags: linux

If a single thread process is currently running and a signal is detected by kernel, does the kernel simply halt the current execution, save the current address space of the instruction pointer and run the signal handler. In other words, it uses the same thread, that was being used by the program to execute the signal handler?
What happens if a process is multi-threaded? If a program have 3 threads and one thread registers the signal handler for say SIGUSR1, will the kernel interrupt the thread that had registered the signal handler and remainder two threads will continue to run?

Comment: Possible duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502011/multi-threaded-signal-handling